# Insert unique values generated by business logic into database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

In my business logic, there is a function that creates a unique value (it is a session id) by a random function.

I have to be sure, that the session id is unique before I store them into database.
So I am generating new session id, until I found one, that is not yet in database.
But there might be a race condition between checking for existing session ids in database and writing it.

The functions for writing and reading in database are using two different connections.
How can I manage this?

I cannot use auto increments, because the next session should not be guessable.

Comment: I would recommend that you take a look at the data type UNIQUE and instead of using your own function to generate an id look at GUID, the race condition could/should be handled with a lock (keyword in .net)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can make this column `UNIQUE` (add database constraint), try to insert new row and check wheter it will return an error about duplicate value. Considering that duplicates are very rare it's probably the fastest and safest method.